# MongoDB: Put document property to listview

Tags: android, mongodb, android-listview

I have a problem to fill a `ListView` in my Android application.
In my database are several documents. All documents have the property `"name".`
Now i want to create a `listview` and fill this `listview` with all documents (only `"name"`).

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far to narrow your requirement.

Comment: I only have create some documents. All documents have this properties: Map<String, Object> docContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            docContent.put("tournamentName", m_tv_TournamentName.getText().toString());
            docContent.put("tournamentType", m_tv_Tournamenttype.getText().toString() );
            docContent.put("nrOfPlayers", m_tv_NrOfPlayers.getText().toString() );
            docContent.put("tournamentMode", m_tv_Tournamentmode.getText().toString() );docContent.put("homeAway", m_tv_HomeAway.getText().toString() ); no I want the tournament name in listview